# Fixed multiple values in slideInput of shiny

Tags: javascript, r, slider, shiny

I want to add a slideInput with multiple fixed values into my Shiny app to show the measurement date of my experiment. The interval of date is random.

This is my testing codes to want to show four dates in sliderInput.

```
library(shiny)
values <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1, 2015-6-20', '2015-7-2', '2016-1-1'))
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    headerPanel("test"),
        sliderInput("foo", "Animation duration", 
                    min = as.Date('2015-1-1'),
                    max = as.Date('2016-1-1'), 
                    value = values,
                    timeFormat = '%d/%m/%Y')
    ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The values also can be updated in the `server.R`.

`selectInput` could be another option, but I prefer to use `sliderInput` which do make sense for date.

I guess I have to manipulate some js scripts, but have no experience about it.

Thanks for any suggestions to implement it.

Comment: Are you asking for only the dates you've specified in `values` to be shown on the slider, and therefore only those dates can be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this with some `javascript`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  headerPanel("test"),

  sliderInput("bar", "bar dates", min=0, max=4, value=c(0,4)),

  tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML("
            $(function() {
              setTimeout(function(){
              var vals = ['2015-1-1', '2015-6-20', '2015-7-2', '2016-1-1'];
            $('#bar').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
            }, 5)})")))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Or, if you prefer the values to be added on the **server** side:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  headerPanel("test"),

  sliderInput("bar", "bar dates", min=0, max=3, value=c(0,3)),
  uiOutput("bar_dates")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

  values <- paste0("'", paste0(c('2015-1-1', '2015-6-20', '2015-7-2', '2016-1-1'), collapse="','"), "'")

  output$bar_dates <- renderUI({

    tags$head(tags$script(
      HTML(sprintf("
            $(function() {
              setTimeout(function(){
              var vals = [%s];
            $('#bar').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
            }, 5)})", values))))

  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update**

I've just seen your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35121917/5977215) that is very similar to this, the answer of which has inspired quite a bit other code I've written.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using sliderTextInput function in shiny. No need to add all this complex js function. Just a few lines of code will do the trick. Do the following :

```
  sliderTextInput("foo","Animation Duration" , 
                  choices = c('2015-1-1, 2015-6-20', '2015-7-2', '2016-1-1'), 
                  selected = c('2015-1-1, 2015-6-20', '2015-7-2', '2016-1-1'), 
                  animate = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                  hide_min_max = FALSE, from_fixed = FALSE,
                  to_fixed = FALSE, from_min = NULL, from_max = NULL, to_min = NULL,
                  to_max = NULL, force_edges = FALSE, width = NULL, pre = NULL,
                  post = NULL, dragRange = TRUE)
```