# Set sliderInput values as characters in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, slider, shiny

My shiny app has a `sliderInput`, but want to replace values as character labels. How could I implement it? Thanks for any suggestions.

This is my example code:

```
library(shiny)
values <- as.factor(c('Label 1', 'Label 3', 'Label 3'))
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    headerPanel("test"),
    sliderInput("foo", "Animation duration", 
                min = 1,
                max = length(values), 
                value = values)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the second line doing? Converting character vectors to dates? That does not work.

Comment: @Gopala. Sorry I have fixed the wrong codes

Comment: If you are really trying to use categorical inputs, you should use selectInput (drop down) or radio buttons. Slider input is really for numeric values, and trying to fit character labels is not the way it is designed to work.

Comment: I understand selectInput is another option, but prefer to use sliderInput in this case. IonRangeSlider, shiny used, can show character in slider. So I think we can do the same thing in shiny, but just not sure how to implement it (May need to write some js script).

Comment: Probably....I can't be of help on that since I have not used custom JS in Shiny.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502870/shiny-slider-on-logarithmic-scale . Basically change the `.update({'values':vals})` to the array of values you want. I just tried changing `vals` to `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ,'five']` and it worked.

Comment: @daattali Thanks for your help. It points me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @daattli for pointing me the right direction and letting me know how to use `js` to change the shiny element.

I have implemented a solution to change labels of `sliderInput` and a `selectInput` to switch different values (and length). I think this feature should be implemented into shiny which uses `ionRangeSlider`.

Please improve my codes if you think there is a better way to implement it, as it is my first `js` script.

```
library(shiny)
values <- list(A = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
               B = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'))

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('selection', 'selection', c('A',  'B'), 'A'),
    uiOutput('selectUI'),
    sliderInput(inputId = "target", label = "Target",
                min = 0, max = length(values$A) - 1,
                step = 1,
                value = length(values$A) - 1),
    verbatimTextOutput('summary')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
        print(input$target)
        print(values[[input$selection]][input$target + 1])
    })
    output$selectUI <- renderUI({

        sel_values <- paste(paste0('"', values[[input$selection]], '"'), collapse = ',')
        print(sel_values)
        list(
            (HTML(
                sprintf('
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        var vals = [%s];
                        $(\'#target\').data(\'ionRangeSlider\').update(
                        {values:vals,
                        min: 0,
                        max: %s,
                        from:%s})
                        })
                        </script>
                        ', sel_values, 
                        length(values[[input$selection]]) - 1,
                        length(values[[input$selection]]) - 1)))
        )}
    )}
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done using sliderTextInput function in shiny. No need to add all this complex js function. Just a few lines of code will do the trick.Install the shinywidgets package which contains the sliderTextInput function. Do the following :

```
  sliderTextInput("foo","Animation Duration" , 
                  choices = c("Label 1", "Label 3", "Label 3"), 
                  selected = c("Label 1", "Label 3", "Label 3"), #incase you want all values by default 
                  animate = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                  hide_min_max = FALSE, from_fixed = FALSE,
                  to_fixed = FALSE, from_min = NULL, from_max = NULL, to_min = NULL,
                  to_max = NULL, force_edges = FALSE, width = NULL, pre = NULL,
                  post = NULL, dragRange = TRUE)
```